# Getting [[Object]] when saving JSON

Tags: javascript, json, save

i am trying to save a json with "somewhere".

This function is incomplete but its enough to show the problem:

```
function testJSON(products) { 
var productsPromises = products.map(function(product) { 
    var title = product['Title']; 
    var stock = product['Stock']; 
    var price = product['Price']; 
    if (stock == "Disponible") { 
        stock = true; 
    } else { 
        stock = false; 
    } 
    var toPush = [{Stock: stock, Price: price}]; 
    var results = {Title: title, Results: toPush}; 
    db.connect('./xxxxx/results.json'); 
    var find = db.find('Productos', {Title: title}); 
    console.log(find); 


}); 
return Promise.all(productsPromises);
```

}

That returns:

```
[ { Title: 'Grabador de voz ISD1932', 
Results: [ [Object] ], 
id: 'f4099bff-fc55-4697-b712-d84343931818' } ] 
[ { Title: 'Arduino SD Card Shield', 
Results: [ [Object] ], 
id: '75c79411-a905-41b3-9578-bb7072139a4d' } ] 
[ { Title: 'Placa prototipo con zócalo para microSD Transflash', 
Results: [ [Object] ], 
id: 'af21962a-197e-43db-aba2-779be95357f2' } ] 
[ { Title: 'Frontal para LCD 32PTU (Negro)', 
Results: [ [Object] ], 
id: '29d1e6cd-b549-44ad-87af-e4a4a056a609' } ]
```

I saved it same way but using

```
 db.save('Productos', results); //instead of db.find(...
```

Why am i getting [[Object]] instead of the data? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `db.save('Productos', JSON.stringify(results));` should do it.